# How to create a list of Sheets based on value found in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have `n` stocks I trade where each stock has a Google Sheet dedicated to it. Each sheet contains one of 3 values in a fixed field (say `A1`). Additionally each sheet contains stock symbol (say `A2`)

**So, A1 has one of the following**

- Add
- Hold
- Reduce

**And A2 has something like**

- MSFT

I would like to dedicate an `Add` sheet that will list symbols that have `Add` in `A1` field.

**So, new `Add` sheet would have `MSFT`, if sheet named `MSFT` has `Add` in `A1`**

How can this be accomplished please?

Comment: read about the FILTER() function

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the following custom function
2. Put `=addStocks()` in any cell of sheet `Add`

Reference:

[Creating a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function)

```js
function addStocks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const values = [];
  for (const sheet of sheets) {
    if (sheet.getName() === 'Add') { continue; }
    const [type, symbol] = sheet.getRange('A1:A2').getValues()[0];
    if (type === 'Add') { values.push([symbol]); }
  }
  if (values.length !== 0) { return values; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the sheet name determines the strategy requested.

1. Create 2 custom functions ([Creating a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function))

```
function GET_SHEET_NAME() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}

function GET_STOCK_SHEETS_BY_STRATEGY(sheetname_is_strategy_requested) {
    var stock_sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

    // So the sheet names that begin with underscores should not be treated as stocks
    // Also the underscore sheet names are used to pass in the strategy_requested
    const strategy_requested = sheetname_is_strategy_requested.toString().toLowerCase().split('_',2)[1];

    var output = new Array( stock_sheets.length+1 );
    output[0] = [ "STOCK" , "STRATEGY" ]; // Header row
    var output_row = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < stock_sheets.length ; i++ ) {
        var loop_sheet = stock_sheets[i];
        var loop_sheet_name = loop_sheet.getName();
        var loop_sheet_strategy = loop_sheet.getRange('A1').getValue().toString().toLowerCase();

        // Filter sheets that begin with underscore and they must match our strategy_requested
        if (!loop_sheet_name.startsWith('_') && loop_sheet_strategy == strategy_requested) {
          output[output_row] = [
            loop_sheet_name,
            loop_sheet_strategy
          ];
          output_row++; 
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

2. In your _Buy sheet, cell A1 put the formula

`=GET_STOCK_SHEETS_BY_STRATEGY(GET_SHEET_NAME())`

3. In a _Sell sheet, cell A1 put the same formula and it will search for 'sell' stocks. GET_STOCK_SHEETS_BY_STRATEGY is case insensitive.

4. You will have to add time triggers if you want to auto refresh the lists.